# Mercurial Time Settings

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time, mercurial, ubuntu-12.04

I wonder about one thing..  I have mercurial version control management installed on linux ubuntu 12.04 as web app, so that we go to mercurial projects through navigating local.mercurial.ge (our domain for instance), then we chose appropriate project and when I look on projects commits the TIME is mistakenly shooted!, like it says unreal/error time, but rather when I go inside by clicking changeset Details, it displays correct time! (underneath of author there is date).
so I checked time on mercurial server (linux machine) there is everything OK,! I can't find out why there is incorrect time in mercurial project's commits and sometimes it is correct.

Please, Help in case!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commit time is taken from the PC on which you entered `hg commit`. Try to find the user who did the commits and let them check their PC's time.

You could also add a [pretxnchangegroup hook](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) to make sure only valid times can be pushed to the server.

Comment: I checked the Computer mentioned.. but nothing useful.. there is set correct time!

and the guy programmer either mentioned the problem that when he Pushed the changeset to the remote centralized repository, he immediately catched the fact that time was set incorrectly..

for more precise clearness:
when I go to mercurial website there is projects, I click on particular project and then seeing Incorrect Commit Time! but when I click on specific Commit (the mentioned one!) inside it there is author and date parameters and within there is correct time !

Comment: I don't see a reason why the web gui should display two different times (or make up a time in the overview and use the correct one in the details view). Which version of Mercurial on the server? What do you see when you run `hg log`?

Comment: Mercurial SCM 2.0.2
Hg log shows the correct times!

[IMG]http://i49.tinypic.com/28u30vq.jpg[/IMG]

even though there is "8 hours ago", it is not correct!, it is 12+8 hours ago (yesterday evening time)

Comment: Looks like a timezone issue. Check timezone settings on the server. Also, looking at your image, both parts say "8 hours ago" so either both are correct or both are wrong.

Comment: You should also try to upgrade to Mercurial 2.3.2 which is the latest version; maybe there was a bug which has been fixed.

Comment: it says 8 hours ago, but in reality the time what is specified on picture is 17 hours ago.
and only SOME commits are acting in such way...

Comment: So in fact both relative times are wrong; the absolute time (with timezone) is correct. Is the Mercurial server in the same timezone as your browser is?